# Can I avoid the processing time when I upload a video to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, video, upload

I uploaded a video file from my phone to Facebook about 9 hours ago, and it still hasn't shown up.  How can I minimize the time it takes to process my video?

Comment: I know this isn't exactly what you were asking, but I have had Facebook drop many, many of my videos over the last week or so. Your videos' failure to show up may not be related to their processing time, but rather to some legitimate bug with Facebook at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

You have nearly no control over facebook's internals. They are known to work on an eventual consistency basis, which could affect whether you see things that you post or upload, particularly from different devices and networks.

I would advise re-uploading the video. You can always delete one of the copies if it turns up twice.

Answer (score 1):

On the Facebook instruction page they say .mp4 videos work best so might be faster.